# Auto-complete cell value when selecting another cell option (data validation)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

[image]

On column "D" I used data validation to select data from column "A". 
When I make a selection on column "D", I want column "E" to auto-complete with data from column "B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in E2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D; A:B; 2; 0)))
```